# Why is $z^2=-1 \implies xy = 0$ for $z = x+iy$?

Tags: complex-numbers

in my mathmatics Skript the soution for the equation

$$z^2 = -1$$

is presented. The proof goes as follows:

Let $ z^2 = -1$ for $z = x + iy \rightarrow x^2 - y^2$ and $xy = 0$. Therefore we have $x = 0$ and $y^2 = 1$ that means $y = \pm 1$. Thus the solution is $\pm i$.

Well $(x+iy)^2 = x^2 + 2ixy - y^2$ but why does this imply $xy = 0$? I really don't get it...

Thank you very much for your help!

FunkyPeanut

Comment: Do you know that $\forall a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R(a+ib=c+id\iff a=c\land b=d)$?

Comment: Yes I know that. But I don't see the Connection between that and my question yet. Let me think about it for a second...

Comment: You also have that $-1+0\cdot i=z^2=(x+iy)^2$.

Comment: And $-1=-1+0i$.

Comment: Aww ya I just saw that, Marc! Grr I've sould have seen that in the first place! Thank you! :)

Comment: Why down vote this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a+bi=c+di$ with $a,b,c,d$ real, then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

The reason is very simple,

$$a-c=(d-b)i$$
and squaring we get
$$(a-c)^2 =-(b-d)^2$$
The LHS is $\geq 0$ and the RHS is $\leq0$, thus to be equal they both have to be $0$.

In your equation you have

$$x^2-y^2+(2xy)i=-1+0i$$

Comment: For the first part of the answer, it can even be a direct consequence of the definition of complex numbers. (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much! I love how fast answers are provided in this community - never seen something like that before! Nice!

Comment: @FunkyPeanut I know, right? I wished I had found out about this before I was close to graduating.

Comment: I feel with you...

Comment: @GitGud It really depends how you define complex numbers. If you define them via matrices, or if you have some background in field extensions, yes it can be just the definition... But in general, if you define them at a more elementary level, the uniqueness of the representation needs to be proven is not just part of the definition...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Conjugating $\,-1 = z^2\,\Rightarrow -1 = \bar z^2.\,$ Multiplying $\, 1 =  (z\bar z)^2 = (x^2+y^2)^2\ $ so $\,\ldots$